# Editing/Creating a foreign key with a drop down list validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a web app, and I can't seem to either create or edit entries with a foreign key.  I'm creating a dropdown list to edit the records, and it's being populated correctly.  But anytime I edit or create a new record with that foreign key I get "The value '2' is invalid."

My Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "chimeTimeID,ScheduleID,ChimeTimeStamp")] ChimeTime chimeTime)
    {
        ViewData["scheduleID"] = new SelectList(db.Schedules, "scheduleID", "ScheduleName", "Select a Schedule");
        ViewBag.defaultModem = new SelectList(db.Schedules, "scheduleID", "ScheduleName", "Select a Schedule");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(chimeTime).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(chimeTime);
    }
```

My View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleID.ScheduleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="dropdown">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ScheduleID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ScheduleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Model

```
[Table("P_ChimeTime")]
public class ChimeTime
{
    [Key]
    public int chimeTimeID { get; set; }
    public Schedule ScheduleID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:T}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ChimeTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?  It appears to me that MVC isn't parsing my result from the form to an int like it should.

Comment: `ScheduleID` is a complex object. You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (and your `ValidationMessageFor()` wont work for the same reason)

Comment: create a property with `int` type  for the foreign key `public int ScheduleID { get; set; }` and another one for `public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }` for your navigational property. Use the name of the property with `int` type  for your form element name.

Comment: Your `LabelFor()` wont work either - you do not have a form control for that property

Comment: My LabelFor() is working properly or at least it has all the right values in it.  My drop down list also has everything that's supposed to be there.  But you're saying that I can't use a select with my Schedule?  Because it's too complex?  How exactly is it too complex?

Comment: A `<select>` binds to a posts back a simple value (e.g. an `int` or a `string`). And your label does not work - click on it an it will not set focus to the associated control. And your editing data so ALWAYS use a [view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). And the refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for typical code togenerating a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is how it should have been:

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "chimeTimeID,schedule,ChimeTimeStamp")] ChimeTime chimeTime)
{
    ViewData["schedule"] = new SelectList(db.Schedules, "scheduleID", "ScheduleName", "Select a Schedule");
    ViewBag.schedule = new SelectList(db.Schedules, "scheduleID", "ScheduleName", "Select a Schedule");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        chimeTime.ScheduleID = db.Schedules.Find (Int32.Parse (Request ["schedule"]));
        db.ChimeTimes.Add(chimeTime);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    buildChimeJob(chimeTime);

    return View(chimeTime);
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.schedule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="dropdown">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.schedule, (SelectList)ViewBag.schedule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.schedule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My Model:

```
[Table("P_ChimeTime")]
public class ChimeTime
{
    [Key]
    public int chimeTimeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule ScheduleID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:T}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ChimeTimeStamp { get; set; }
    [ForiegnKey("ScheduleID")]
    public int schedule {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I gave you links and hints showing how to do this correctly. If you want to write bad code, go ahead, but please do not associated me with it (now edited out)